# In Microsoft Access, how to make the first letters of a compound word, with or without hyphen(s), be automatically capitalised?

Tags: ms-access

When the user enters "anna mae", it should turn to "Anna Mae", and "anna-mae" should turn to "Anna-Mae".

Comment: There isn't an universal way to do that. For example, both spellings for the names `Macdonald` and `MacDonald` are in use. Thus, without extra info, one cannot capitalise properly `macdonald`.

Comment: In my application, I was doing it on insert but not on update. So they could correct the auto capitalisation.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called Proper Case or Title Case, and it sounds like there are ways to accomplish it in MS Access via these docs: [How to convert data values of the Text data type to the proper case format in Microsoft Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/convert-data-values-of-text-data-type).

But logical limitations exists such as what vonPryz mentioned. So it's not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

- Give code to the "after insert" textbox control
- Give the same routine to the "after update" event

```
Sub AfterUpdateOrInsert
  txtName.text=StrConv(txtName, vbProperCase)
End Sub
```

You may improve this by first assigning it to a local variable and doing a binary text compare